# Search for empty arrays in mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I needed some help with the atlas search aggregation query.
I want to use $search syntax  while doing the atlas search :
I have one collection; inside which I have one array field of ObjectIds like so :

`arrayFieldOfObjectIds : [ObjectId(62ff26c349a3c47656765434), ObjectId(62ff26c349a3c47656765435)]`

Now the array fields can also be empty in some cases like so :
`arrayFieldOfObjectIds : []`

I have defined the correct index mapping for this field.
My goal is to get all the documents that met the below conditions:

```
1. Either arrayFieldOfObjectIds doesn't exist.
2. If arrayFieldOfObjectIds does exist, it must be empty.
3. If arrayFieldOfObjectIds does exist, it must be equal to some specified value.
```

The query I have for arrayFieldOfObjectIds is :

```
{
  "compound": {
    "should": [
      {
        "compound": {
          "mustNot": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "path": "arrayFieldOfObjectIds1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "equals": {
          "value": ObjectId("62ff26c349a3c47656765434"),
          "path": "arrayFieldOfObjectIds1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "minimumShouldMatch": 1
  }
}
```

This query doesn't give me those documents where `arrayFieldOfObjectIds` does exist and is empty.
Note: I need to use `$search` syntax and I also don't want to combine `$match` with `$search` as it kills the query performance altogether.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate why do you need to use `$search` ?

Comment: cause I need to have full-text search and I am replacing elasticsearch with mongo atlas. $search gives so many options to do it efficiently, like custom analyzers, and operators which you don't get in normal mongo queries.